# How to find the exact time a tweet was tweeted

Tags: twitter

So on the Twitter website, underneath the post there's a timestamp, but it's not very specific - it will just say something like Jul 10, or 11 hours ago or something like that.  Is there any way to find the EXACT time a tweet was posted?  Like to the second?  I want to avoid messing around with programming or dealing with the API if possible, but I've looked all over, and haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible without getting down in HTML or using an extension that does what I am going to do. It was most likely formatted this way to be more friendly to the wider audience.

Right click the time link and inspect the source with an approriate browser.

[image: Web Inspect with Chrome]

You should see something similar to the following.

```
<div class="stream-item-header">
<small class="time">
<a href="/codinghorror/status/94410540117536768" class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink" title="10:16 AM - 22 Jul 11">
<span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp " data-time="1311344201" data-long-form="true">22 Jul</span></a>
```

`data-time` has all the information you need. For example, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Alpha) to convert it.

[image: Input Format]

[image: Converted time]

Quicker ways include

- using a JavaScript console and `Date()` (new Date(1311344201000);)
- the [`show` API method](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/id)
- Use another Twitter application and use [ChrisF's method](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17533/how-to-find-the-exact-time-a-tweet-was-tweeted/17534#17534) to rollover to see:

[image: Blackbird embed]

Comment: Does this method still work? When I tried on sample URL twitter.com/petermortensen/status/88211587667738625 (known to posted on 2011-07-05, within Unix time range 1309755600 - 1309928400) I could not locate anything resembling the expected Unix time in the HTML source.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Twitter decided to remove it for reasons that leave me staring at the wall with long blank stares. The only way now would be either via the API or a Third Party. Wrong move by Twitter imho.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I found it again. It's there.

Comment: jut search for data-time in the inspector

Answer (score 4):

Hover over the "23 seconds ago" link. It will bring up a tooltip with the exact date and time it was posted.

However, this is only to the minute, not the second.

Comment: That just gives the time to the minute, not the second.  I'm pretty sure there's a way to do that though, I just don't remember.

Comment: @Shravas - oh, missed that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The methods in the other answers don't work anymore for more than minute precision, however there is a new-ish one: you can tweet

> [@tweet_stamp](https://twitter.com/tweet_stamp) stamp

in a reply to the tweet whose timestamp you want, and this account will very quickly reply to you with a link to data including the timestamp. You can also just DM the link to it.

Comment: Works great 2021, ty!

Answer (score 0):

You can view the timestamp down to the second by using the mobile version of the site.  *(NB: You need to be logged-in to see it.)*

https://twitter.com/markphillip/status/711966337078198273

https://mobile.twitter.com/markphillip/status/711966337078198273

Answer (score 0):

Just hover the mouse over the time stamp "Jul 10" and it will create a dialogue bubble with the full time it was tweeted.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient online service is now available which can convert both Twitter's "Snowflake" tweet ids and the pre-2010 ids to timestamps. Great for deleted tweets, especially pre-Snowflake ones:

- [TweetedAt: Find the date and time of a tweet](https://oduwsdl.github.io/tweetedat/)

Read more at

- [TweetedAt: Finding Tweet Timestamps for Pre and Post Snowflake Tweet IDs](https://ws-dl.blogspot.com/2019/08/2019-08-03-tweetedat-finding-tweet.html)